# Why is file_create_url() returning inconsistent values?

Tags: uri, media, files

I'm experiencing an inconsistent behaviour in Drupal 7 on the function `file_create_url()`. I have one field collection with 4 fields in it. On the first field the function provides the correct file url. For the other 3 fields it displays only first part of url. How can I get rid of this?

Here is my code:

```
<video controls="controls"  autoplay="autoplay" poster="<?php print file_create_url($content["field_poster"][0]["#item"]["uri"]); ?>" style="width:100%"   >
  <source src="<?php print file_create_url($content["field_mp4"][0]["#item"]["uri"]); ?>" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="<?php print file_create_url($content["field_webm"][0]["#item"]["uri"]); ?>" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="<?php print file_create_url($content["field_ogg_theora"][0]["#item"]["uri"]); ?>" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

And here is the result: *field_poster* is fine but the others fail;
[image]

```
<?php print_r($content["field_poster"][0]); print_r($content["field_mp4"][0]); ?>
```

leads to...

```
            Array
(
[#theme] => image_formatter
[#item] => Array
    (
        [fid] => 288
        [uid] => 1
        [filename] => Transgourmet_Waldputen_MASTER.jpg
        [uri] => public://Transgourmet_Waldputen_MASTER.jpg
        [filemime] => image/jpeg
        [filesize] => 65241
        [status] => 1
        [timestamp] => 1440456242
        [type] => image
        [rdf_mapping] => Array
            (
            )

        [image_dimensions] => Array
            (
                [width] => 1008
                [height] => 573
            )

        [alt] => 
        [title] => 
        [width] => 1008
        [height] => 573
    )

[#image_style] => 
[#path] => 
)
Array
(
[#theme] => file_link
[#file] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fid] => 289
        [uid] => 1
        [filename] => Transgourmet_Waldputen_MASTER.m4v
        [uri] => public://Transgourmet_Waldputen_MASTER.m4v
        [filemime] => video/x-m4v
        [filesize] => 34256348
        [status] => 1
        [timestamp] => 1440457177
        [type] => video
        [rdf_mapping] => Array
            (
            )

        [display] => 1
        [description] => 
    )

)
```

Is it possible that is has to do with the mime-types?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you reorder them will the first path in the collection always be correct, no matter the field? Have you tried to print out your field values outside of the collection?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reordered them bit nothing interesting happened: ´field_poster` is correct, `field_mp4` fails....moreover when i ´print_r($content['field_mp4'][0])` ist display an object with the right file infos in it. When I try access ist it fails....

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of a silly question now that I think about it, since this is manual, not dynamic, output. What does the print_r() output look like for `$content['field_poster']` and `$content['field_mp4']`? For sake of comparison can you include it in your post?

Comment: Thanks. I completed my question in the way you suggested. Any idea? :)

Comment: When I try to access the object via `["#file"]` instead of `["#item"]` the whole site fails...

Comment: I was just going to suggest that. Well, at least we know why `$content["field_mp4"][0]["#item"]["uri"]` doesn't work. Try `$content["field_mp4"][0]['#file']->uri`. I see now that is an object, not an array.

Comment: Sometimes it's such a little thing you can't see it. :-) Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the video files, this (for example):

```
$content["field_mp4"][0]['#item']['uri']
```

should be this:

```
$content["field_mp4"][0]['#file']->uri
```

Change `#item` to `#file` and change the syntax to reference an object instead of an array.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to upvote right at the moment :) But I labeled it as solution.

Comment: No worries. :-)

Comment: Just to get a learning out of it: The one is an array and the other is an object? Is that the reason for different syntax?

Comment: That's exactly right. This is where the `print_r()` (or better, `dpm()` if you use the Devel module) comes in handy, since you can see things like that in the output.